# breaker trips when switch is turned OFF

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker

I have installed two LED pots in parallel, controlled by SPST switch. The lights are from Amazon (China?), the 14/2 wire and 200a Siemens panel are from Home Depot. The 15a breaker came with the panel.

- I wired the lights by pushing the 14/2 wires into the supplied "auto-crimp" connectors.
- I wired the switch(es) by adding 6" leads to all four poles. Both grounds were connected to the box and I used a marette to connect the ground from the switch.
- Neutral / white was connected with a marette between switch, panel-wire and load-wire.
- The panel-hot wire was connected to the bottom pole with a marette, and the load-hot wire was connected to the top pole with a marette.

If I turn the breaker on while the switch is OFF, the breaker immediately trips. If I turn the breaker on while the switch is ON, the lights turn on and everything looks good. As soon as I turn the switch off, the breaker trips. I changed out the switch, and the behaviour is consistent.

I have never seen this sort of behaviour. Where should I start looking?

Comment: Can you add a picture of the wired switch, its kind of hard to follow what you did from the text.

Comment: Is the breaker a regular breaker, or an AFCI or GFCI type? (Does it have a TEST button on it, for one?)

Comment: An SPST switch does not have four poles...

Comment: Why is neutral going to the switch?

Comment: Is your 15A breaker and AFCI or GFCI or Combo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wiring a neutral to a switch would be impossible without making it non-functional, unless you used a 3 way switch instead of a standard one. That would also explain the behavior. if there are three screws on the switch, you used the wrong type. The Neutral should not go to the switch, EVER.

Comment: The lightbulb in my mind turned on a few seconds ago. I rushed back here hoping nobody had seen the question yet... :) Thanks!